# PHP replacing first ? in querystring with & symbol

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

*(LAMP Stack running on CentOS 6, PHP 5.3.3, httpd version 2.2.15)*

I'm trying to pass the entire querystring to my PHP script, but if the querystring contains any question mark characters, the first ? character is getting replaced with an & character.

In access_log, the correct querystring is displayed including the question mark.

However, if I echo the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] global, the first ? is replaced.  So I assume the translation/normalization is taking place somewhere in PHP.

For example: http://l.sitename.com/IsThis?thequerystring?

We expect $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to be "IsThis?thequerystring?"
But instead, it is actually "IsThis&thequerystring?"

Here's the access_log entry:

```
"GET /IsThis?thequerystring? HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "-"
```

Here's the .htaccess entry:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^l\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/link.php?$1    [NC,L,P,QSA]
```

Strangest thing: it *was* working but now it's not after installing updates (CentOS, HTTPD, PHP, etc).

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Why would `/IsThis?thequerystring?` as an example even be what you are considering a valid URI?  There should only be one `?` in the URI that is not URL encoded.

Comment: @mike i want people to be able to manually pass complete URLs to this page.  For example http://l.example.com/http://www.google.com?query=whatismyname?&otherparam=asdf

Comment: Then those URL's should be URL-encoded. If yo do that, your problem goes away ans you can properly use SQA flag as you should be able to do if you want to add your own parameters to cases where some parameters are already passed before rewrite.

Comment: How would you URL-encode a manually-entered url?  I want the user to type the url in the Address bar with no need to fill in a form.  Can you do url encoding in .htaccess on manually entered urls? Note again that they will be typing/pasting the url direclty into the address bar, with no pre-processing on it, and we need to capture anything they throw at it. Thanks.

Comment: OK. That is a weird use case, typically when talking about passing parameters, you are not expecting someone to be manually typing them into the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `QSA` flag otherwise `?` gets converted to `?`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^l\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/user.php?$1 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^l\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/user.php?$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,P]
```

With this you will get:

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] = IsThis?thequerystring?
```

Comment: This *almost* works.  However, it adds the trailing question mark even if there is no querystring.  For example, http://l.sitename.com/ThisHasNoQuestion - $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] = "ThisHasNoQuestion?".  How can I omit the question mark if the querystring is blank?

Comment: Sorry to be bothersome, but this didn't work as expected. 

Example URL: http://l.example.com/asdf?1234

Result:
502 Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /asdf.
Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 

access_log entry:
"GET /asdf?1234 HTTP/1.1" 502 379

Somehow, the "link.php" part is getting left out entirely.
Same thing happens if I omit the question mark and just use: http://l.example.com/asdf

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it didn't show any line breaks.  access_log should be on a new line.

Comment: Hooray! It works!  I didn't know the order of RewriteCond lines mattered.  Why does this particular order make any difference?

Comment: Actually I am not entirely sure but I guess captured groups from `RewriteCond` only work from closest conditions from `RewriteRule`.